# How to convert the query result to a dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, postgis, polygon, geojson

I want to show a geojson output in python.

I use this command:

`func.ST_GeometryN(ResultTable.geom, 1).ST_AsGeoJSON()` as well as

`ST_AsGeoJSON(func.ST_GeometryN(ResultTable.geom, 1))` and I got the same output:

```
{\"type\":\"Polygon\",

\"coordinates\":[[
[-0.100025584382582,51.3304330070013],
[-0.098511161418636,51.3319822092096],
[-0.095612305682008,51.3319351077536],
[-0.0942280582731,51.3303388127129],
[-0.095742562708752,51.3287896679662],
[-0.098641233092886,51.328836760799],
[-0.100025584382582,51.3304330070013]
]]}
```

How can I remove the extra slash `\` ?
The problem is that I use it in a query and I convert the result in a nested json.  The whole code is:

```
def get_forecast_json(db: Session, instance_id:str, limit: int = 100)-> Query:

 out_sq = (
    db.query(
        ResultTable.point_id,
        ResultTable.measurement_start_utc,
        ResultTable.NO2_mean,
        ResultTable.NO2_var,
        func.ST_GeometryN(ResultTable.geom, 1).ST_AsGeoJSON().label("geom")
    )
    .filter(ResultTable.instance_id == instance_id)
    .limit(limit)
 )
```

How can I convert the query result `out_sq`  to dictionary, to avoid the double json conversion?
Please any advice will be helpful.

Comment: you did this is geopandas or PostGIS?

Comment: I use geopandas

Comment: `func.ST_GeometryN(HexGrid.geom, 1).ST_AsGeoJSON()` is geopandas? what is `func`? what is `HexGrid`?

Comment: Sorry, it is `ResultTable` , it is a table that gives points in a specific time

Comment: this is not geopandas